# Drop down field shows values of all users

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form field in Django called Label. My problem is that the field shows the Labels of all users while I only want to show self created labels.

**models**

```
class Label(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag

class Birthday(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, default="")
    day = models.DateField()
    label = models.ForeignKey(Label, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=0, null=True, blank=True) 

    def __str__(self):

        return self.name
```

**forms**

```
class BirthdayForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Birthday
        fields = ('name', 'day', 'label')

class LabelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Label
        fields = ('tag',)
```

**template**

```
            <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                <table border="0">
                    {{ form }}
                </table>
                <button class="submitButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

This is the view for this template

**view**

```
@login_required
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BirthdayForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            birthday = form.save(commit=False)
            birthday.user = request.user
            birthday.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        #default_labels("Friend", request)
        #default_labels("Family", request)
        form = BirthdayForm()
    birthday = Birthday.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    username = request.user
    return render(request, 'bd_calendar/index.html', {'form': form, 'birthday': birthday, 'username': username })
```

Comment: what is self created labels ?

Comment: Show your views function where you retrieve labels.